# Least notes money exchange

Tags: code-golf, math

Suppose A and B are two good friends. A has borrowed \$n\$ dollar from B. Now B wants the money back from A and A is also ready to give it. But the problem is A has only \$x\$ dollar notes and B has \$y\$ dollar notes. They both want to keep the number of notes in exchange as low as possible.

As an example if \$n=37\$, \$x=5\$ and \$y=2\$, then the least amount of notes in exchange will be nine $5 notes from A and four $2 notes from B, which totals to $37.

Your input will be \$n, x, y\$ and your output should be the least of amount of notes possible for \$A\$ and \$B\$ such that \$B > 0\$. Input and output seperator can be anything, no leading zeros in input numbers, no negative numbers in input. Standard loopholes apply and shortest code wins.

**Test Cases**

```
37 5 2 -> 9 4
89 3 8 -> 35 2
100 12 7 -> 13 8
10 1 100 -> 110 1
```

Input will be always solvable.

Comment: Are all inputs guaranteed to be positive integers? Does B always use notes (should `10, 1, 100` give `10, 0` or `110, 1`?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Input is always postitve integers and Everyone use notes

Comment: Please update the question. Especially for "Everyone use notes" two of the three answers so far do not do that, and it's not obvious.

Comment: ...although I don't see why the friends would bother doing `110, 1` when they could do `10, 0`!

Comment: That really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Needing B to give back at least one note strikes me as a needless gotcha.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
n,x,y=input()
c=n+y
while c%x:c+=y
print(c-n)/y,c/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtRCsMgEAX/PcUiFJRsiZqWpAFPswgRylaKoXp6axJ4HzMwL9W8fdi13xbfAewaSiApZWMsWH3ktGelBXkeqrgaupWVBl9F@kbOiu6sx4o0lnb81DQjPBGcFmp5IUwIS0drDIJ1CPMpnfuM6fLo4o7@Dw)

-8 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: 69 bytes. Nice.

Comment: Save 8 like [this](https://tio.run/##JYtRCsMgEAX/PcUiFJRsiZqWpAFPswgRylaKoXp6axJ4HzMwL9W8fdi13xbfAewaSiApZWMsWH3ktGelBXkeqrgaupWVBl9F@kbOiu6sx4o0lnb81DQjPBGcFmp5IUwIS0drDIJ1CPMpnfuM6fLo4o7@Dw)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, that's smart. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
1 :'1+[:($#:u i.~,)[:+//(,-)*/1+[:i.u+]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcmxDoIwFEbhnaf4oyZtpS29rQS4iZOJk5MrcTIScXFi9dUrFxwczvKdV954NeDIULAI4DnncbpezpnAisqe9W7LE0b/sabnsqq0dWZfyRn9VN5UNsXj/nyjhk4NBoNYrNDhAMf/vnCqEcUTdNuJt6tTQitOEZpCkNP8DgXQsuTImH/@Ag)

A bit labored as J code, but the idea is simple.

We construct a table with all the possible linear combinations, and just find the coordinates of what we're looking for:

[image]

In the actual code we drop the first column (because of the B > 0) constraint, and then have to add 1 to the returned coords, to adjust for 0-indexing.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <sup>14</sup> 12 bytes

```
b;.z₂×ᵐ-~h?∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSu9qhtw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wP8larwrIPTwdyNGty7B/1LH8///oaGNzHVMdo1idaAtLHWMdCyDD0MBAx9BIxxzM1DHUAfJjYwE)

The albeit strange constraint that the outputs must be `≥1` helps, as Brachylog tries only positive numbers for multiplication.

```
b;.z₂×ᵐ+~h?∧  [37,5,2]
b             [5,2]
 ;.           [[5,2], output]
   z₂         [[5, A], [2, B]]
     ×ᵐ       [5 * A, 2 * B]
       -      5 * A - 2 * B
        ~h?   [5 * A - 2 * B, X, Y] = [37, 5, 2]
           ∧  return the output [A,B] and solve the constraints
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 54 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,x,y,i=0)=>(i-n)%y||n>i?f(n,x,y,i+x):[i/x,(i-n)/y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjT6dCp1In09ZA09ZOI1M3T1O1sqYmzy7TPg0mpV2haRWdqV@hA5bWr4z9n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaZhbK5jqmOkqfkfAA)

Javascript beats Python!

Comment: my 2 preferred languages all gone... and I'm bad enough that I can't out golf u guys

Comment: Since I golfed 8 off the Python answer, I'll put JavaScript back in front with the same change [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjT6dCp1In0zZPu1LT1i5TtcI@DSYGFLGKztSv0NHI1M3T1K@M/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYWyuY6pjpKn5HwA) :)

Comment: 52 bytes: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjT6dCp1LT1i7dViPC1gDI0Ei1rdCK0M3TVK2sybMDMu3TNSK0DTWtoiN0UvUrY/8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaRib65jqGGlqaGr@BwA at the cost of calling `f(37,5,2)()` instead of `f(37,5,2)`

Comment: And 50 bytes: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18jT6dCp1LT1i7dViPC1gDI0Ei1rdCK0M3TVK2sybMDMu3TNSK0DTWtoiN0UvUrY/8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaRib65jqGGlqaGr@BwA if function is unnamed

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice optimization!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>14 13 12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

-1 thanks to [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy)! (Dividing through and keeping those invariant under flooring is terser than testing divisibility and then integer dividing.)

```
‘r×ṀɗĖ÷ḞƑƇḢ
```

A dyadic Link accepting `amount owed` and a list of denominations `[y, x]` that yields a list of `[B gives, A gives]`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4oCYcsOX4bmAyZfElsO34biexpHGh@G4ov///zM3/1syLCA1XQ)**

#### How?

```
‘r×ṀɗĖ÷ḞƑƇḢ - Link: integer, n; list of integers [y,x]
‘           - increment (n)
    ɗ       - last three links as a dyad - f(n+1,[y,x]):
   Ṁ        -   maximum ([y,x])
  ×         -   (n+1) multiplied by (that)
 r          -   inclusive range -> [n+1, n+2, ..., (n+1)×max([y,x])]
     Ė      -   enumerate -> [[1,n+1],[2,n+2],...]
                   (...note that this equals [[n+1-n,n+1],[n+2-n,n+2],...])
      ÷     -  divide by ([y,x])? (vectorises)
         Ƈ  - keep those which are:
        Ƒ   -   invariant under:
       Ḟ    -     floor
          Ḣ - head
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 45 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>n=>(g=m=>m%x?g(m+y):[m/x,(m-n)/y])(n+y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpbCoMwFITh9@5DmMGKN4q2cNKFFB9EUCycICqSrD4NSEEY/oeP@fZHvw3rvOzZ0YZRghPjxVgxmETFaOLeEzT1fH00d3doZpn7jrDRwrLOdseIB1ERdUPe/lQTbdzzQmX8NERZFFc8IYYMPw)

Comment: change your name to "tsh the outgolfer" :P

Comment: Ah, a curried version of what I commented a few mins earlier ([TIO](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjT6dCp1In0zZPu1LT1i5TtcI@DSYGFLGKztSv0NHI1M3T1K@M/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYWyuY6pjpKn5HwA)). I don't know JS syntax well enough for that!

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```js
(n,x,y)=>g=(B=1)=>(n+=y)%x?g(B+1):[n/x,B]  // 41 bytes, original

(n,x,y)=>g=B=>(n+=y)%x?g(-~B):[n/x,-~B]    // 39 bytes, user l4m2’s improvement
```

### 41 bytes, original

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bczBCoJAGATge0/hJfb/cSpXCzX4C/Y1ooMEynrYxETWp9@2Q1DgbWC@mb6Zm9djtMO0m6vQSiAHj4Xl0gkZ0TGQS2Xhrb92ZFLN55s7eJh7GEbrJmqpKHFCzsT7/mkdKShORCRRNY6KN19W1ShQrbAirn@czjLoHOWK1PHgT0Ij8jX56RSHNw)

The formula to satisfy is `A * x = n + B * y`, or `A = (n + B * y) / x`. Since we are looking for an `A` that is an integer, we try `B = 1, 2, 3, …` until `n + B * y` is divisible by `x`.

For `B = 1, 2, 3, …`, we have `A * x = n + y, n + y + y, n + y + y + y, …`, so we can reuse `n` to store `A * x` and increment it by `y` at the beginning of each iteration.

The solution is similar to [Redwolf Programs’](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225267/103803), and is equally 41 bytes long, but IMHO its form is different enough to merit being a separate answer, and the function accepts the arguments in a more natural form `f(n,x,y)` rather than `f(n,x)(y)`.

### 39 bytes, user l4m2’s improvement

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bczBCoJAGATge0/hJfb/aSxXCzX4DXyN6CCBoodNTGS99OrbdggK9jYw38zQLM3zPvXjHC@Fa8WRgcXKUnVSS0VmJytv7aWj@FXz@WoOFj7d3Dj1ZqaWshwnpEy8Hx69IQXFkYhEqsRR8ebLihIZigDL/PrH6SSBTpEHpPYHfxIanofkp1Ps3g)

`~B` gives the 2’s complement of `B`, which for non-negative integers is equivalent to `-(B + 1)`. So `-~B` is equivalent to `B+1`… with the difference that `~B` implicitly casts `undefined` to 0, so we no longer need to initialize `B=0`. What a trick!

Comment: [39](https://tio.run/##bczBCoJAGATge0/hJfb/aSxXCzX4DXyN6CCBoodNTGS99OrbdggK9jYw38zQLM3zPvXjHC@Fa8WRgcXKUnVSS0VmJytv7aWj@FXz@WoOFj7d3Dj1ZqaWshwnpEy8Hx69IQXFkYhEqsRR8ebLihIZigDL/PrH6SSBTpEHpPYHfxIanofkp1Ps3g)

Comment: Nice trick @l4m2, I updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>47</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

*-5 from @Arnauld*
*-1 from @tsh*

```javascript
(n,x,b=0)=>g=y=>(++b,n+=y)%x?g(y):[n/x,b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCoMwEEbhfU@RTWF@MsWoiLEw9iDFhQqKLoKoiDl9tIuCbr/3xnqrl3YepvW12dBJIMc7N2IgZS9eStK6YafF47l/evJ4f110HlWY5sGt1FGas8pACfD4ky1YpSB7odgYVnECym94Gn4NCAc)

**Old:**

```javascript
(n,x,b=0)=>g=y=>(a=++b*y+n)%x?g(y):[a/x,b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfI0@nQifJ1kDT1i7dttLWTiPRVls7SatSO09TtcI@XaNS0yo6UR@oJPZ/QVFmXolGmoaxuY6CqaaGkaYmF0zIwlJHwVhTwwJJyNDAQEfB0EhTwxxFECimCZLT1PwPAA)

**Old:**

```javascript
(n,x,y)=>(g=b=>(a=b*y+n)/x%1?g(b+1):[a/x,b])(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchBCsIwEEbhvaeYjTBjf2mmRRqF6EHERSK01EUotZT09DEbQeHxFt/Lr/79nMdpOa429y5zRMIm7sqDC@XehcNWRanTXm8Dh0rlcvd1QngIq@RpHuPCPbcd6ARqRHZfsmdQC7I/pMaAtAF1f1isZIxI/gA)

Comment: I'm sad now. 47 because outer function doesn't need to be named.

Comment: Do you need to name `f`? Also imagine being able to do two lambdas without spending like 20 bytes on `lambda ...:`

Comment: @hyper-neutrino ninja'd

Comment: @Ausername Good point (also @hyper-neutrino). I'd been recursing with `f` previously :p

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfI0@nQifJ1kDT1i7dttLWTiPRVls7SatSO09Tv0LV0D5do1LTKjpRH6go9n9BUWZeiUaahrG5joKppoaRpiYXTMjCUkfBWFPDAknI0MBAR8HQSFPDHEUQKKYJktPU/A8A) by taking `(n,x)(y)`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're doing `/x%1`. So, [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfI0@nQifJ1kDT1i7dttLWTiPRVls7SatSO09TtcI@XaNS0yo6UR@oJPZ/QVFmXolGmoaxuY6CqaaGkaYmF0zIwlJHwVhTwwJJyNDAQEfB0EhTwxxFECimCZLT1PwPAA), I guess?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, but `(n,x,b=0)=>g=y=>(++b,n+=y)%x?g(y):[n/x,b]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y,n,s=1:s+n%x and 1j+f(x,y,n+y,0)or n/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoUKnUidPp9jW0KpYO0@1QiExL0XBMEs7TQMsoV2pY6CZX6SQp1/xv6AoM69EI03DVMdIx9hcU5MLJmCsY6FjYYkkYGikY65jaGCALATiA7Gm5n8A)

Output as the format `(9+4j)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⁺×…·¹θＮＮη≔⌕﹪ηθ⁰ζＩ⟦÷§ηζθ⊕ζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY09C8IwFEV3f0XGF6jQujh0KoqQoVLETRxi8mgD6avNR5H@@VgR0cHhDgfuuVd10qlB2pQE3WM4xv6GDkZerirvTUvQ2OjhbHr0IEgtYCY8SWoRioyNPGO/Hv/D3XfrYEhDPehoB@jedr5kXhqNMxRgJ32Ai6CwN5PRCFUQpPHxKs/8c6cc9kgBNcz8ynmZUrFhW1bkeVpP9gk) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `x y n`. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `x`.

```
≔⁺×…·¹θＮＮη
```

Form a range from `1` to `x`, multiply each element by `y`, and add `n`.

```
≔⌕﹪ηθ⁰ζ
```

Find the index of the first multiple of `x`, which is also `1` less than the number of notes for `B`.

```
Ｉ⟦÷§ηζθ⊕ζ
```

Calculate the number of notes for `A` and output the results on separate lines.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

Similar idea as [Jonah's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225272/64121), but quite a bit shorter due to APL's 1-indexing.

```apl
{⊃⍸⍺=⊃∘.-/⍵×⊂⍳⍺+⌈/⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRV/Oj3h2PenfZglgdM/R09R/1bj08/VFX06PezUBx7Uc9HSCh2v9pj9omPOrtA@tY86h3y6H1xo/aJj7qmxoc5AwkQzw8g/8bmyukKZgqGHFZWAIZxgoWXIYGBkCWoZGCOZAJYimARAA)

A dfn which takes `n` as left input `⍺` and the array `x y` as right argument `⍵`:

```apl
             ⍳⍺+⌈/⍵   ⍝ indices from 1 to n + max(x, y)
          ⍵×⊂         ⍝ multiply x and y with each index
     ⊃∘.-/            ⍝ create a table of all pairwise differences
   ⍺=                 ⍝ for each value: does it equal n?
 ⊃⍸                   ⍝ get the first index of a 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>54</s> 50 bytes

```r
function(n,x,y){while((m=n+T*y)%%x)T=T+1;c(m/x,T)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/rv4@fravs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6dCp1KzujwjMydVQyPXNk87RKtSU1W1QjPENkTb0DpZI1e/QidEsxasUcPYXMdUx0iTC8yxsNQx1rGAcgwNDHQMjXTM4VwdQx2gmOZ/AA)

Port of [@hyper-neutrino's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225265/55372).

*-4 bytes thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

---

Port of [@tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225273/55372):

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 53 bytes

```r
f=function(n,x,y,s=1)"if"(s+n%%x,1i+f(n+y,x,y,0),n/x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcs7CoAwEITh3mMIQpYMmFVELVLaqZcQAmlW8AHJ6aMEsfz@YY40r8tkk7Pulu3yuyhBQMRpmUrvSnVqqaoA9top0TGPhiB1oPxVbY8ODRUZw4gWwwc2Btyg/wnG2yg9)

---

Other ports of [@hyper-neutrino's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225265/55372):

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 54 bytes

```r
function(n,x,y,K=n+y){while(K%%x)K=K+y;c(K/x,(K-n)/y)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/rv4@fravs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6dCp1LH2zZPu1KzujwjMydVw1tVtULT29Zbu9I6WcNbv0JHw1s3T1O/UrMWrFnD2FzHVMdIkwvMsbDUMdaxgHIMDQx0DI10zOFcHUMdoJjmfwA)

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 54 bytes

```r
function(n,x,y,K=n){while((K=K+y)%%x)0;c(K/x,(K-n)/y)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/rv4@fravs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6dCp1LH2zZPs7o8IzMnVUPD29Zbu1JTVbVC08A6WcNbv0JHw1s3T1O/UrMWrFnD2FzHVMdIkwvMsbDUMdaxgHIMDQx0DI10zOFcHUMdoJjmfwA)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/rv4@fravs/rTQvuSQzP08jT6dCp1KzujwjMydVQyPXNk87RKtSU1W1QjPENkTb0DpZI1e/QidEsxasUcPYXMdUx0iTC8yxsNQx1rGAcgwNDHQMjXTM4VwdQx2gmOZ/AA) by getting rid of the repeated ```(n+T*y)``` expression in the last one...

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>79</s> 63 bytes

```java
(n,x,y)->{int a=n/x,b;for(;(b=++a*x-n)%y>0;);return a+" "+b/y;}
```

*Saved 16 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236).*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7BboMwEETP5StWkSrZYSGQKEoqi/xBTxyrHgyByBQMsg0CIb6d2qHXKntZjfbNzFZ84EF1/1lF07XKQGV12BtRh3vmdX1WixzymmsNn1xImD2wI6QpVMnzAtK2Hgo1p0YJ@QDtFLFXkOggGLc1UbY8jX@B2nBj19CKOzQ2lmz@r2/g6qHp7L1tuVAmK5E44kSD2@ySeCIPI2asbBVhJEt8n@/HQNL36RYxylRheiWB@zvY@dlhYsvKnsVu0kmbognb3oSdrTO1JGW4vXy64BmPlDLb/D91/cATXl9RcRRhfMTLaw5jtLDj3HuLt6y/)

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##nY9NboMwEIXX5RSzqWSHgUCiKKksIvUAXbGsujCJiUzBINtQEOLs1EAP0HY286P53rwpeMeD4v45y6qptYXC9WFrZRnumNe0WSlvcCu5MfDGpYLRAxdSWaFzfhOQ1mUn9OgG7x9gloa4GhQuO9BvaaBsWrkfPWO5damr5R0qp0pSq6V6OAWuH4aO3tMmC3kyE4U9DjS4LjeAJ2rf@zFmLK81YSRL@K4PFH0erhHjvk@ZFrbVCpT4gtXUyDHbDxObZrZaWCIdjBVVWLc2bNxhWyryqjUfTGjrzQrJw@2Z4xlPeKCUMmfq99jlBY94@TMWRxHGBzz/A8QYHb2Cy4uTN83f) by using `b` (which you somehow kept while it was useless) to store store `a*x-n`.

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY7BboMwEETP5StWkSrZYSGQKEoqi/xBTxyrHgyByBQMsg0CIb6d2qHXKntZjfbNzFZ84EF1/1lF07XKQGV12BtRh3vmdX1WixzymmsNn1xImD2wI6QpVMnzAtK2Hgo1p0YJ@QDtFLFXkOggGLc1UbY8jX@B2nBj19CKOzQ2lmz@r2/g6qHp7L1tuVAmK5E44kSD2@ySeCIPI2asbBVhJEt8n@/HQNL36RYxylRheiWB@zvY@dlhYsvKnsVu0kmbognb3oSdrTO1JGW4vXy64BmPlDLb/D91/cATXl9RcRRhfMTLaw5jtLDj3HuLt6y/) by switching output type from `int[]` to `String`, and merging the `+1` and the `a++` to a prefixing `++a`.

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY7BboMwEETP5StWkSrZwRBIVCWVRf6gJ45VD1sCkSkYZBuEhfh2aodeq@xlNdo3M1vjiFF9@1lF23fKQO10PBjRxHse9MN3IwooGtQaPlBImANwI6QpVYVFCXnXjKWac6OEvIP2irgrSOYhmLZlKV8exr9AbdC4NXbiBq2LJZv/8wtQ3TWdg5ctF6psJZJNzNLoOvskzGRoedUpwvF1uiacYphZrkozKAl4mMId7EKCkaQHy5eVP2r95Fabso27wcS9KzONJFW8PXw6szd2pJS73v@pyzs7scszKk0Slh7Z@TnHUuZgz/n3lmBZfwE) by rethinking the entire algorithm (that's really different from what you wrote)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
(x#y)n=[(div(n+i*y)x,i)|i<-[1..],mod(n+i*y)x<1]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7BjoIwEAbge59ijCa2WlgKGjVSn8A3IBy6aVcnQkuAKCS@O7ZGL3ub@f6ZyVxVdzNVNU10mI/MyoJqvFO7xtXIBo7siXlUiDguee3013NRzmbJVCu0UjsCFLljefRXq4bq1jWQsrhrlKU/chktWb44XUx/RmsIVKYvLB/4WMrWKO2jh2t1B3gsFP/9h/5006Lt6ec5Sf0M4@99HkoC4Ycp28EWUohOcIAN2R8gg33oMq9EJAmIFHYBhA88gICgAULzAg)

The relevant function is `(#)`, which takes as input integers `x`, `y`, `n` and returns a pair `(a,b)`, meaning that A should give `a` notes and B should give `b` back.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>60</s></sup> 58 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [G. Sliepen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46301/g-sliepen)!!!

```c
f(n,x,y,s){(n+=y)%x?f(n,x,y,s+1):printf("%d %d",n/x,s+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJ/T4MwEP1/n@JCsoSOWwbDZT9w@ofxUzhjSCmTOLsFiLYufHXxKHRjOkmuae@9e313lI/5Lpbbuk5diQo1FuzoSm@t2VDdn3JewFaHPJNl6jrDBIaJg3KiTD6qasrDe5xJt9nE@ZYj8Nc4H42awwcbHAdAXwOWoihf5NMzrOEYzhEWS4TA95ulii5ZqmXNEEKCpxS/GbplELRAmBuhHkWog@ClSKwQ3RSSWNCoBVeJnd4NQitpLzS90Cr4m8iJAw3L2ajH6UYtHyhmDkL/HDpdZbrPwQwlk4lQVOZH3fYWiuxL7FP3bJNNutSol4vA80wFg3aK1rUktW6aBn@OLmBlYXUV1hbWf@Dzb0ZoA8Z3QB1KBIWg2Zlqn4fPLtVNq735X3MgdJ/zvw04TWgF5uWxjSQzgqwI66UaVPU3T3fxtqjHnz8)

Uses the formula from [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)'s comment to [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225265/9481).

Comment: A recursive version in 58 bytes: `f(n,x,y,s){(n+=y)%x?f(n,x,y,s+1):printf("%d %d",n/x,s+1);}` Basically a port of @dwardu's answer.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Good idea but the problem with recursion like that is it's dependent on \$s\$ picking up its \$0\$ initialisation from the stack, which may or may not be \$0\$.

Comment: Undefined behavior is perfectly acceptable for Code Golf. If it runs on tio.run, it is fine ;)

Comment: @G.Sliepen True, don't know why I think like that golfing - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
∞*.Δ²@²y-³Ö*}D²α³÷,¹÷,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8Lb1zUw5tcji0qVL30ObD07RqXQ5tOrcRyNyuc2gnkPj/39CIy9DAgMscAA)

A port of hyper-neutrino's [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225265).

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8LW2XQ5tVDbJd7HQOrzi0@fB2nf//jbiMzblMAQ) with input as `y, n, x`. (Some savings are probably from Jonathan Allan's golf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```ruby
->n,x,y{[1.step.find{(n+=y)%x<1},n/x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5Pp0KnsjraUK@4JLVALy0zL6VaI0/btlJTtcLGsFYnT78itvZ/gUJatLG5jqmOUex/AA)

#### How

The trick is in `1.step.find`: we add y to n at least once, and count iterations until n is divisible by x.

Outputs `[B,A]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 75 bytes

```lua
load('n,x,y='.. .....' c=n repeat c=c+y until c%x==0 print(c/x,(c-n)/y)')()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZLCsAgDADRq2RTjNT6OYCHkdSFIKmIgp4@bYe3mDqTSH3SjYrNMjsqa8H@KaDI0HPLaXxL54bJo1SgY8XoofXCA8ktg3SxdlsrjVpEgjcQPt6/)